# Listening to a channel (laravel-echo) in Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js, laravel-echo

I am trying to build a chat application using Laravel and Next.js. Since I am using WebSockets, I believe I should append the incoming messages inside the ".listen()" method in an array (useState), and it will be re-rendered as it gets updated. But to do that, I would have to use .listen() method inside the react function. But .listen() is not working inside the react function. It is working outside.

So, this code can listen to broadcasts

```
import echo from "@/lib/echo";

const channel = echo.channel("chat");

channel
  .subscribed(() => {
    console.log("subs !");
  })
  .listen(".chat_message", (event) => {
    console.log("listening");
    console.log(event.message);
    // console.log(messages);

    //   setMessages((messages) => [
    //     ...messages,
    //     {
    //       className: "chat-end",
    //       text: event.message,
    //     },
    //   ]);

    //   console.log(messages);
  });


const Chat = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([
    { className: "chat-end", text: "message" },
  ]);

...
}

export default Chat;
```

But this cannot listen.

```
import echo from "@/lib/echo";



const Chat = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([
    { className: "chat-end", text: "message" },
  ]);

  const channel = echo.channel("chat");

  channel
    .subscribed(() => {
      console.log("subs !");
    })
    .listen(".chat_message", (event) => {
      console.log("listening");
      console.log(event.message);
      // console.log(messages);
  
      //   setMessages((messages) => [
      //     ...messages,
      //     {
      //       className: "chat-end",
      //       text: event.message,
      //     },
      //   ]);
  
      //   console.log(messages);
    });
}

export default Chat;
```

`@/lib/echo`

```
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

const options = {
  broadcaster: "pusher",
  client: new Pusher(`${process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY}`, {
    cluster: "NaN",
    wsPath: process.env.PUSHER_APP_PATH,
    wsHost: process.env.PUSHER_HOST,
    wssPort: process.env.PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    wsPort: process.env.PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    forceTLS: (process.env.PUSHER_SCHEME ?? "https") === "https",
    enableStats: false,
    enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
  }),
};

const echo = new Echo(options);

export default echo;
```

Please help me to fix this. And if this approach is wrong, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NEXT_PUBLIC before key name, it is a must

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34798896)

Answer (score 0):

We finally did make a prototype for this solution. If someday someone  bump into this problem, here it our take on this

1. avoid the hook and initialize echo in useEffect(() => {}, [])
2. make sure in your .env.local file you have "NEXT_PUBLIC_" prefix (I did not have it before) [Thanks @joeeee]

ref:
`https://github.com/ravgeetdhillon/chat-app-nextjs-laravel-ably.git`

Here is our sample code:

```
import axios from "@/lib/axios";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

const Chat = () => {

  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: "pusher",
      client: new Pusher(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_APP_KEY}`, {
        cluster: "NaN",
        wsPath: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_APP_PATH,
        wsHost: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_HOST,
        wssPort: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
        wsPort: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
        forceTLS:
          (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? "https") === "https",
        enableStats: false,
        enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
        //   channelAuthorization: {
        //       transport: 'ajax',
        //       endpoint: `...`,
        //       headersProvider: () => {
        //           //
        //       },
        //   },
      }),
    });

    const channel = echo.channel("chat");
    const allMessage = [];

    channel
      .subscribed(() => {
        console.log("You are subscribed");
      })
      .listen(".chat_message", (event) => {
        // setMessages((oldMessages) => [...oldMessages, event.message]);
        allMessage.push(event.message);
        setMessages(allMessage);
        setMessage("");
      });
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (message !== "") {
      axios.post("chat-message", {
        message: message,
      });
    }
  };

  return ();
};
```

[image]